# react native can't find variable center

Tags: react-native

When ever I try to position my text center I get the error that variable 'center' can not be found. Am I doing something wrong or is did I not do it correctly?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';


type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
render() {
  return (
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.titel}>Random Text</Text>
    </View>
  );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  titel:{
     color: 'black',
     justifyContent: center,
     alignItems: center,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`center` is not a **variable**, it is a **string** therefore you need to add it as

```
  titel:{
     color: 'black',
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Real stupid from me to make such a beginner fault